# Normal convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I am asked to show that the following series of functions does not converge normally.

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{x+n} $
I showed that it converges simply (over $\mathbb{R}^+\cup 0$) and tried to show its uniform convergence through that of the series’ remainder, but I fell short.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may consider showing, for any fixed $n\geq 1$, that $$\sup\Bigg\{\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+x}\Big)\Bigg| x\geq 0\Bigg\}$$ equals $+\infty$

Comment: @MatthewH. I thought so. But how do I show that? thank you for your response.

Comment: Fix $n_0\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and assume this set is bounded above by some $M>0$. Since $\sum_{k=n_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}=+\infty$ you can find $n$ so that $\sum_{k=n_0}^{n}\frac{1}{k}>M.$ Can you find $x$ so that $\sum_{k=n_0}^{n}\Big(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x+k}\Big)$ remains larger than $M$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to evaluate the maximum value of $[\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{(n+x)}]$ over $\mathbb R^{+}$.

It is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Thus the series is not normally convergent.

Comment: "Serie" is not a word in the English language...

Comment: @XanderHenderson maybe English isn't this person's first language